# Using environment variable with or without curly braces causing issue

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

This is to know the reason of issue.

Scenario: I have created environment variable to access mysql like this
        $MYSQLCMD="mysql --user="root" --password="***" DB" 
added to .bashrc

Now, i have created a script which looks somthing like this:

```
 sql_script="/home/test/scripts/update_table.sql"

 start_date=`date --date='1 day ago' +%Y-%m-%d`
 end_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

 echo "Starting cron for start_date=$start_date to end_date=$end_date"

 $MYSQLCMD -e "set @start_date=\"$start_date\"; set @end_date=\"$end_date\"; source ${sql_script};"
```

Now, i am using this script to run as a cron job everyday, now next thing i have added a cron task to my crontab like this;

```
00 20 * * * /home/test/scripts/update_db.sh > /home/test/cronlogs/cron_`date +\%y\%m\%d`.log 2>&1
```

which will run everyday at 8 PM.

Now the problem when this cron runs it always prints this error:

```
/home/test/scripts/update_db.sh: 12: /home/test/scripts/update_db.sh: -e: not found
```

But if change the the MYSQLCMD is being called in the script with curly braces like: ${MYSQLCMD} then this works fine.

It's not making any difference when i am running from command line.
After confusion, I even changed #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh, just to check.
Now i still don't understand the reason behind this.

Comment: The mostly likely problem is that `.bashrc` isn't being sourced, either because cron uses `sh` instead of `bash` to execute the script, or because `.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive shells. Put all the relevant credentials in `update_db.sh` itself, rather than relying on any particular environment.

Comment: It's working..thanks. But I have to use same env variable, as i have to share this same script with others without them changing username or password...